# Change variable value when checkbox is checked/unchecked

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I was trying to change the value of an variable according to the status of an checkbox
here is my code sample

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(document.getElementByType('checkbox').checked)
{
var a="checked";}
else{
var a="not checked";}
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML ='result '+a;
</script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1"/>Checkbox<br/>
<br/>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Can you please tell me whats the problem with this code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]').checked) {
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o51cw8rc/)

Code suggestion:

```
<input type="checkbox" />Checkbox<br/>
<span id="result"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var input = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');

    function check() {
        var a = input.checked ? "checked" : "not checked";
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'result ' + a;
    }
    input.onchange = check;
    check();
}
</script>
```

In your post you have the javascript before the HTML, in this case the HTML should be first so the javascript can "find it". OR use, like in my example a `window.onload` function, to run the code after the page loaded.

Comment: its working but how to make it onload I mean when page is opened then it should display **"result not checked"**

Comment: @Subhanker, updated my answer. I made a new function and added a call to it att the bottom `check();`

Comment: Now there is no effect when checkbox is checked/unchecked please review

Comment: the variable a here is local is there a way to alter an global variable

Answer (score 3):

```
            $('#myForm').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
                this.checked ? this.value = 'apple' : this.value = 'pineapple';
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function update_value(chk_bx){
        if(chk_bx.checked)
        {
            var a="checked";}
        else{
            var a="not checked";
        }
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML ='result '+a;

    }

</script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" onchange="update_value(this);"/>Checkbox<br/>
    <span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: @Subhanker its working check correctly just copy and paste it and use

Answer (score 0):

Too complicated. Inline code makes it cool.

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="yourBooleanVariable=!yourBooleanVariable;">
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who tried the previous options and still have a problem for any reason, you may go this way using the .prop() jquery function:

```
$(document.body).on('change','input[type=checkbox]',function(){
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == 1){
        alert('checked');
    }else{
        alert('unchecked');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This code will run only once and check initial checkbox state. You have to add event listener for `onchange` event.

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementByType('checkbox').onchange = function() {
        if(document.getElementByType('checkbox').checked) {
            var a="checked";
        } else {
            var a="not checked";
        }
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML ='result '+a;
    }
}
```